# Cron job which will work under Linux and Windows

Tags: python, excel

I've constructed a python script `python_script.py` in Linux. Is there a way to do a cron job which will be compatible with Linux and Windows. In fact, even tough I have implemented this script in Linux, it will be run under a cron job in Windows.

Otherwise, assume the script works well on Linux and Windows. How could we create an automatic task on Windows (similar to a cron job on Linux)?

Comment: How are you running  python_script.py? Are you using a bash script and passing it as an argument inside crontab. i,e, * 1 * * someuser bash_script_to_kick start_python_script

Comment: Windows doesn't have cron

Comment: @zee I don't even think how to run my python_script.py yet, but probably with a management command.

Answer (score 0):

Create an automatic task using scheduler in windows.create a bat file to run the Python script and schedule that ask from the windows scheduler.hope this helps